# Java How to add data in two tables (Relational database)

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I'm making a desktop app in Swing.
Here's the problem:

I have two tables - `suppliers` and `items`.

```
supplier  supplierid(PK,AI),name,address,telephone
item     itemid(PK,AI),supplier_supplierID(FK),name
```

Questions:

- how do I insert in `supplier` and `item` tables at the same time? Does foreign key in `items` adds by itself or do I have to do it explicitly?
- how do I add only item for a specific supplier? I was thinking about some list, dropdown menu to choose supplier -> get his PK and insert into item table.

I'm using Netbeans, MySQL

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far? You can't insert in 2 tables at once. You will need to run two distinct `INSERT INTO` statements.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you're trying to access your database.
Using a ORM like Hibernate and similar will do the most of the work for you because it's handling dependencies between Entities.

If you access your DB using plain JDBC, well you should insert the "rows" manually in the correct order.
So you should insert the supplier first and then the depending item.
If the supplier already exists, you should get it's id first and pass that value as supplier_supplierID when saving the item.

But this all has nothing to do with Spring!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the parent row (supplier) first, and then the item.  Otherwise you will get an error.

When you add the supplier you use the new supplier_id as the value for the item.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not the  best but it works , first of all first insert some data in your primary table then you get that primary id you replace it with the 7 in the foreign key position in this code . so once it works then find a way to deal with the foreign key I did not work on it

```
     try {   


          String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbtec";          

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userdb,pass);

         PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(" INSERT INTO supplier(name,address,telephone
) VALUES(?,?,?)");
         statement.setString(1,"stackoverflow");
         statement.setString(2,”15 newyork”);
         statement.setString(3,"+19898989");
         statement.executeUpdate();
                  statement.close();

         /// Insert into another table 

         PreparedStatement statement2= (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO item(supplierID,name) VALUES (?,?) ");
         statement2.setString(1,"7");
         statement2.setString(2,"Bruce");
         statement2.executeUpdate();
                  statement2.close();   
                  conn.close();
     }
     catch(SQLException e){
         e.printStackTrace();

     }  catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(newclient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```